# Bazel not allowing Go debug.ReadBuildInfo() passthrough?

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-gazelle, bzlmod

I'm new to Bazel and cannot understand why Go `debug.ReadBuildInfo()` is not usable for me.

I have a `debug.ReadBuildInfo()` wrapper function `internal/version/info.go` in codebase which outputs a marshalled JSON output via an exported `BuildInfoJSON()` function, so it looks like this:

```
// Basic wrapper around stdlib debug.ReadBuildInfo()
func BuildInfo() (*debug.BuildInfo, error) {
    info, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to retrieve build info")
    }
    return info, nil
}

// Marshals output from debug.ReadBuildInfo() into JSON format
func BuildInfoJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    info, err := BuildInfo()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    json, err := json.MarshalIndent(info, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to retrieve build info: %v", err)
    }
    return json, nil
}
```

I then have a command under `cmd/foo/main.go` which imports `version` (i.e. `import (info codebase/internal/version)`) and displays it if a `version` flag is set (code below is simplified pseudo-code):

```
    if *version {
        info.BuildInfoJSON()
    }
```

But when I compile with Bazel and call `info.BuildInfoJSON()` in `main()`, I get the following, I get an error `failed to retrieve build info` (which is bubbled up from `debug.ReadBuildInfo()` in my version function).

I am using Bzlmod with Gazelle to auto-generate `BUILD.bazel` files.

The auto-generated `BUILD.bazel` for `internal/version` is :

```
load("@rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")

go_library(
    name = "version",
    srcs = ["info.go"],
    importpath = "codebase/internal/version",
    visibility = ["//:__subpackages__"],
)
```

The auto-generated `BUILD.bazel` for `cmd/foo` is :

```
load("@rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")
load("//rules/go:rules_go.bzl", "go_binary")

go_library(
    name = "foo_lib",
    srcs = ["main.go"],
    importpath = "codebase/cmd/foo",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = [
        "//internal/version",
    ],
)

go_binary(
    name = "foo",
    embed = [":foo_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Of course everything works perfectly if you directly call `debug.ReadBuildInfo()` within `main()` but that's not what I want, because I am keen to avoid code duplication.

Comment: "Of course everything works perfectly if you directly call debug.ReadBuildInfo() within main()" -- do you know why it works when called from main but not called indirectly? Might be good to investigate there -- are you sure it works? Have you seen this issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/3090 Have you tried passing --stamp on the command line?

Comment: @ahumesky Perhaps I should have phrased better, perhaps better phrased as "within the same package/bundle", i.e. in other words "it words perfectly" as in the way it would be done without bazel, i.e. simple app with optional sub-dir layout under the same tree (`/app-dir/cmd/main.go` `/app-dir/lib/version/info.go`)compiled manually with go.